# What compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion should we use for current situation?

Tags: android, android-studio

As in title. Which SDK version should we target right now for application that will be published to store?

What about target 20 and buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'?

Answer (score 3):

It depends directly of your app type and devices you want it installed.

As you can see in android dashboard 80% of devices are over 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich API 15) https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

So a good aproximation for min SDK could be API 15.

On the other hand, for most apps, your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion should compile against the latest version of SDK (API 19 KitKat)

Edit:

API 20 is the version of the new Android L, which today is a preview, and Android Wear. If you are developing an app for Android L or wearables your targetSdkVersion should be 20 and you will compile it with the version 20 of the buildTools.

But as i said before API 20 is a preview and there is no comercial devices with this Android Version yet.

Comment: As in edit: What about target 20 and buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'?

Answer (score 0):

The latest SDK version which is available is 19, so if you want to cover the latest devices, you need to set the `targetSdkVersion` as 19

Answer (score 0):

Always set target sdk to latest sdk released. Right now I'd go for:

```
... gradle build script ... 

compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
minSdkVersion 10 // if supporting 2.3 devices and up
targetSdkVersion 19

..
```

Comment: As in edit: What about target 20 and buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'?

Comment: @Mikooos go for it, ps: code above is from my latest project few weeks ago